# What tool to use to retrieve data from database stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, data-access-layer

I have a stored procedure which will be used to populate a report in ASP.NET. My application mainly contains SELECT queries and it has to be developed quickly and be changeable in the future.

I'd need to decide which tool to use to work with this stored procedure.

Factors:

1. Speed of Development with above average performance
2. Maintenance
3. Future support and stability of the technology
4. Performance

My options are:

- Plain ADO.NET: which makes my development slow whereas it has to be finished in 2 days.
- LINQ to SQL
- Entity Framework 4.0
- Enterprise Library Data Access
- ...?

It's been a long time I haven't used any of these.

Please advise.

Comment: Which is going to take longer, using ADO which you apparently already know, or learning L2S or EF in a day and a half and then writing the code in the remaining half day? In a crunch, go with what you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're simply calling a stored procedure and getting the results, I would stick with plain ADO.NET.

There's no reason to go over the time limit (it really should only take an hour or so) and you won't have any ORM headaches to deal with.

Comment: Thanks, where can I find a source code for a good pattern to implement plain ADO.NET? e.g. using Repository pattern e.t? I don't think implementing the data access layer from scratch is quicker than using an ORM e.g. L2S.